# adoptopenjdk - select a specific minor version of the OS

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, openjdk-11, adoptopenjdk

In my docker file I use

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.10_9-alpine
```

(origin: https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11)

This installs alpine version 3.14 as can be seen here:

https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/master/11/jdk/alpine/Dockerfile.hotspot.releases.full

Is it possible to choose a higher minor version?

A critical vulnerability (CVE-2021-36159)in alpine is fixed starting 3.14.1:

https://alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-3.14.1-released.html

What can be done to mitigate this risk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AdoptOpenJDK's openjdk-docker images are deprecated.

From [Readme](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker#readme) of AdoptOpenJDK's openjdk-docker.

> ## ⚠ DEPRECATION NOTICE ⚠
>
> ---
>
> These Dockerfiles along with their images are officially deprecated in favor of the [eclipse-temurin image](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin/), and will receive no further updates after 2021-08-25 (Aug 01, 2021). Please adjust your usage accordingly.

So, there won't be any update on the AdoptOpenJDK's openjdk-docker images you should move to [eclipse-temurin image](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin/).